# AcquireTokenAsync failed with UserAssertion in Web API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

A Web API has been developed which uses ADAL .Net v3.14 for authentication. Now here is code to get access_token (Using default TokenCache provided by ADAL)

```
var provider = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com"
var service = "https://XXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com/XXXXXXService" //which is registered as service in Azure AD
var clientId  = "01d2b529-XXXX-XXXX-b794-XXXXXXXXXXXX" //client app registered on Azure AD
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(provider);
UserPasswordCredential uc = new UserPasswordCredential(user, password);
AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(service, clientId, uc).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

It successfully returns Access_Token. Now After 1hour when this token is expired, I have implemented following code to renew it using Refresh_Token (assuming refresh_token will be taken from cache as implemented ADAL TokenCache) :

```
  AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(provider);
  UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(oldtoken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", upn);
  AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource,clientId, userAssertion).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  var token = result.AccessToken
```

This code gives error :

> "Invalid JWT token. AADSTS50027: Invalid JWT token. Token format not valid".

I checked 'oldtoken' variable, it's valid JWT token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you acquire the access token ? On web api side or client side ?

If you acquire access token on web api side using resource owner password grant flow  . And want to renew the access token using refresh token . You just need to use your acquiring token function again since you are acquiring token directly use user's credential .

If you acquire access token on client side , and use that access token to access your web api , then client app should be responsible for checking valid access token and renew access token using refresh token .

Comment: Hi, I am renewing token at web api side, isn't that possible to just use userId to renew token instead of user-credentials at web api side ?  Also, how client app ( like AngularJS SPA) will able to do, as these apps will call our Web API to get access_token

Comment: web api side can't renew access token since no refresh token exists in token cache . If client is AngularJS SPA , you can use ADAL JS ,it examines the projected expiration of the existing token (in the cache) and if the token is about to expire, it uses an invisible iFrame to send a new token (renewal) request to Azure AD.  See document [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/) . And refer to [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi) .

Comment: thanks for help, I was passing wrong clientId, because of which it failed to get a new token