# ADAL failed to return token in webAPI. Error:Invalid jwt token using userassersion

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, adal

A native app created which is calling web api.Two apps has been created in the azure.Here is the code code for getting access token and it worked well,I am getting access token:

```
UserCredential uc = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);
result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId,clientId, 
uc).Result;
```

Now to access new token after the expiry of old one(1 hr) i am using the code:

```
 AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(oldToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", userName);
        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, userAssertion).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

But I am getting Error as:"Invalid JWT token. AADSTS50027: Invalid JWT token. Token format not valid".
Checked JWT token :it is correct in format can able to decode using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).
Note:  client Id am using for these two code snippet are the same appId.

I know this is the exact duplication of the question [asked by devangi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645429/acquiretokenasync-failed-with-userassertion-in-web-api).I cannot able to comment on that question that's why I am asking it again.
Any one can able to help me out?

Or

It will be great if any one can able to help with other ways to get token with out using user password since i need to internally generate new token without user enter password again.

Comment: Please explain more about your scenario? you want to refresh token in client side or web api side? Please refer to [authentication scenarios for Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios)

Comment: @Nan Yu It is in web api side

Comment: You are acquiring access token for web api in native app , then native app should check the lifetime of access token and acquire a new one if token is expired .

Comment: @Nan Yu   No Web api itself getting access token for app by using client Id since our business requirement is something like that.

Comment: please refer to my reply and choose the flow .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the scenario when user has authenticated on a native application, and this native application needs to call a web API. Azure AD issues a JWT access token to call the web API. If the web API needs to call another downstream web API, it can use the on-behalf-of flow to delegate the user’s identity and authenticate to the second-tier web API .

Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of) for more details about On-Behalf-Of flow . You can also refer to [code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof) .

For the scenario when  when a daemon application(Your web api) needs to call a web API without user's identity , you should use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service)  to use its own credentials instead of impersonating a user, to authenticate when calling another web service. Code sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples#server-or-daemon-application-to-web-api) is for your reference .

Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) for explanation about above two scenarios. Your code is using Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant ,this flow has multi restrictions such as don't support 2FA and is not recommended .

If i misunderstand your requirement , please feel free to let me know .